# cmd call function not successful (with errorlevel)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

code :

```
@echo off
set mode=1
echo.------------------------
echo.^|  GAME LAUNCHER V.1.0 ^|
echo.^|                      ^|
echo.^| -------------------  ^|
echo.^| ^|  LOAD NEW GAME ^|  ^|
echo.^| ^|   GET NEW GAME  ^|  ^|
echo.^| -------------------  ^|
echo.------------------------
choice /c WSADK /n
if %errorlevel%==5 (
if %mode%==1 (
goto game.load
) else (
goto game.get
)
) else (
if %mode%==1 (
set mode=2
) else (
set mode=1
)
)

if %mode%==1 (
call main.mode.1
) else (
call main.mode.2
)

:main.mode.1
cls
echo.------------------------
echo.^|  GAME LAUNCHER V.1.0 ^|
echo.^|                      ^|
echo.^| -------------------  ^|
echo.^| ^|  LOAD NEW GAME ^|  ^|
echo.^| ^|   GET NEW GAME  ^|  ^|
echo.^| -------------------  ^|
echo.------------------------
goto :EOF

:main.mode.2
cls
echo.------------------------
echo.^|  GAME LAUNCHER V.1.0 ^|
echo.^|                      ^|
echo.^| -------------------  ^|
echo.^| ^|   LOAD NEW GAME ^|  ^|
echo.^| ^|  GET NEW GAME  ^|  ^|
echo.^| -------------------  ^|
echo.------------------------
goto :EOF


:game.get
cls
echo.Press any button to get games......
pause >nul
start http://tool-box.weebly.com/

:game.load
echo BUILDING......
pause >nul
```

Window disappeared immediately after pressing

> <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks okay. There is only one moment for input, which lets you choose beween W, A, S, D and K. If you choose any value other than K, `mode` will be set to `2`, causing a call to `:main.mode.2`. From that label, you echo a bunch of lines and jump to :EOF, ending the subscript.

After that, the main script continues from the call, basically executing from `:main.mode.1` onwards, which also echoes some lines, and then jumping to `:EOF` again, ending the main script.

[edit]

Reading it again, and correcting it. The above *would be true* if the call would work in the first place. But for `call` to work on a label, you have to prefix the label name with a colon. Since you don't, I guess the script tries to start an external script named 'main.mode.2', which probably cannot be found. So the script displays an error and continues running, encountering a `goto :EOF` soon after, which ends the script.

**Tip**: to debug scripts like this, open `CMD` and run the script from there. Then the window will remain open, and you can inspect a little better what actually happened.

Comment: why `jump` but not `call`? i use `goto :eof` to end the call. what's the problem? should i add `goto` after the two if statement?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the call. After returning from the call, the script continues sequentially, echoeing the lines after `:main.mode.1` and also ending the script, because there it says goto:EOF as well.

Comment: Come to think of it, for call you need to add `:` before the label name, otherwise it will be interpreted as the name of an external script.